# Pages not in use

Tags: 7, views, nodes

How can I find all the nodes that are no longer in a menu?
I've created a view that manage those nodes. Nodes can be find on a search but they are no longer in the main menu.

Comment: You can compared from an old backup DB

Comment: you are right Neograph734 is the same issue, but my is a little bit  complicated. I sign up again. thanks a lot.